# Google Tag Manager no longer in preview mode for any version

Tags: google-analytics

When I'm trying to preview and debug the marketing pixel tags for my website in [Google Tag Manager](http://www.google.com/tagmanager/), I immediately see the message

> Preview Confirmation
>
> You are no longer in preview mode for any version of container GTM-XXXX

and I'm unable to preview and debug my site. What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this answer](http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/tag-manager/MVIj7rtf3Pk/qr6LJ_q4z9kJ) in the [Google Product Forums](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/en), you will get the above message immediately if you have 3rd-party cookies blocked in your browser:

> same happend to me until I enabled to accept 3rd partie cookies in firefox!

If you unblock 3rd-party cookies or somehow make an exception rule for Google Tag Manager in your browser, then the preview and debug should work properly.